# PostScript Error: Error: undefined; OffendingCommand: xyshow; ErrorInfo: MetricsCount --nostringval--

Tags: pdf, command, postscript

I am getting this error while distilling PS to PDF.

```
%%[ Error: undefined; OffendingCommand: xyshow; ErrorInfo: MetricsCount --nostringval-- ]%%

Stack:
[8.707 0.0]
(B])
[1 0]
(B])
2.67572
74.6978


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

I am not expert in PostScript and going thru the manual but I am able to make up that there are certain problems in couple of art images, which are causing the issue.  My main concern is that these arts are provided by third party and I need to give them an appropriate feedback so it should not repeated.

Can I do something in my distiller settings (advanced: on/off) to avoid this error? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Best,
PC

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it appears there is not going to be anything you can do. The PostScript program (yes PostScript is a programming language) contains an error.

From the back channel error report it 'looks like' the xyshow operator has been given a single pair of numbers to draw a string which contains 2 characters (and would therefore need 2 pairs of numbers).

However that **should** produce a rangecheck error, not an undefined, so possibly that's not the real underlying problem. It's also complaining about MetricsCount which isn't standard PostScript at all and makes me wonder if this is a problem specific to your interpreter.

What are you using to turn the PostScript program into a PDF file ? Adobe Acrobat Distiller ?

You could try running the PostScript program through Ghostscript and see if that works. Or if you make the program available I could look at it. Unfortunately it's pretty much impossible to tell you anything more without seeing the PostScript.